# working with List<product>

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, data-binding

I am getting list of items from database using list<>. In description, I don't want to use same approch as I did for getting product name and price.

```
List<Products> product = productBL.AllProducts();
ddProductName.DataTextField = "ProductName";
ddProductName.DataValueField = "ProductId";
ddProductName.DataSource = product;
ddProductName.DataBind();  
ddProductPrice.DataTextField = "ProductPrice";
ddProductPrice.DataValueField = "ProductPrice";
ddProductPrice.DataSource = product;
ddProductPrice.DataBind();
```

I dont want to use following for description.

```
productDescription.DataTextField = "ProductDescription";
productDescription.DataValueField = "ProductDescription";
productDescription.DataSource = product;
productDescription.DataBind();
```

Is there way to write that :

```
productDescription.Text = product.Description;
```

because description is read only , so why should I write 2 more lines.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. Please re-read from our perspective and edit.

Comment: Yeah, please rewrite it as it's not clear what is your question.

Comment: My request is not to use databind() for getting description. I want to write 2 less lines in code..

Comment: `product` is a list, so how can it have a `Description` field/property? What are `ProductDescription`, `productDescription`, `ddProductName` etc? You are presenting a set of disconnected snippets with insufficient info to work out what you are asking, let alone what the solution might be.

Comment: @DavidArno ddProductName is dropdown list to show user products. and sorry for typing mistakes. Description is text box to show a brief description..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not clear at all.
But,
Like if you want to display your Product Name as well as it's description to your dropdown item then,create another property which concatting this two:

```
Product.NewPropertyName = (ProductName + Description)
```

and bind like

```
ddProductName.DataTextField = "NewPropertyName";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (Products p in product)
{
    ProductDescription.Items.Add(p.ProductDescription, p.ProductDescription)
}
```

It's either that or using your data-binding expression you've written above. There is no simpler way to populate a dropdown list with items besides what you've written and what I have written above.